# How can I start a process with any name which does nothing?

Tags: bash, process

I want to start a process that does nothing but is still running. Say I start a process called `sadhadxk`, and when I run `pgrep -x "sadhadxk"` I will get the PID number back, like any normal process works.

So is there any way to start a dummy process?

Answer (score 16):

You could do:

```
perl -MPOSIX -e '$0="sadhadxk"; pause' &
```

It should set both the process name and argv[0] on systems where it's supported so should show `sadhadxk` in both `ps` and `ps -f` output, so should be matched by both `pgrep -x` and `pgrep -fx`.

Answer (score 10):

```
> bash -c 'exec -a sadhadxk sleep 1000000' &
```

`pgrep` doesn't work but

```
> ps | grep '[s]adhadxk'
18931  [...] sadhadxk 1000000
```

Correction: `pgrep` does work but not against the command name (which is the name of the running binary), only against the command line:

```
> pgrep -f sadhadxk
18931
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this :

```
sleep 600 &
```